# MYSQL: slow performance on join tables

Tags: mysql, performance, join, explain

I have this 3 tables, but when I join with the **ref_practice_invoice_payment** the query takes longer (about 5 seconds++).

The query is as follow:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM practice_invoice_detail PID 
  LEFT 
  JOIN ref_practice_invoice_payment RPIP 
    ON RPIP.timestamp = PID.timestamp 
   AND RPIP.practice_id = PID.practice_id
   AND RPIP.refunded <> 1 
   AND RPIP.other_bill = 0 
  JOIN practice_invoice_header PIH 
    ON PIH.timestamp = PID.timestamp 
   AND PIH.practice_id = PID.practice_id 
   AND PIH.is_active = 1
WHERE PIH.source = 'E' 
   AND PID.practice_id = 28618 
   AND (
         (RPIP.pay_cal_id >= 201805130 AND RPIP.pay_cal_id <= 201805200) 
       OR (PIH.cal_id >= 201805130 AND PIH.cal_id <= 201805200 AND PIH.total_invoice = 0 AND PID.item_comission_type <> '%')
           )
```

Below is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `practice_invoice_header` (
 `timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `practice_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `cal_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `source` char(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'E = ENCOUNTER; P = OTHER (PHARM / LAB)',
 `total_invoice` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `total_procedure` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `total_pharmacy` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `extra_charge_ph` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `total_lab` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `total_voucher` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `total_base` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `procedure_base` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `pharmacy_base` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `lab_base` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `clinic_share` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `tax` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `other_bill` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `changed` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `paid` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `covered_amount` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `reff_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `notes` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
 `custom_invnum` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `insurance_plan_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `outpx_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `cancel_reason` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 `pharm_read` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `lab_read` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `rad_read` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ph_checked_by` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ph_checked_time` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`timestamp`,`practice_id`),
 KEY `source` (`source`),
 KEY `reff_id` (`reff_id`),
 KEY `practice_id` (`practice_id`),
 KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
 KEY `is_active` (`is_active`),
 KEY `custom_invnum` (`custom_invnum`),
 KEY `insurance_plan_id` (`insurance_plan_id`),
 KEY `practice_id_3` (`practice_id`,`reff_id`),
 KEY `ph_check_status` (`ph_checked_by`),
 KEY `cal_id` (`cal_id`),
 KEY `outpx_id` (`outpx_id`),
 KEY `practice_id_8` (`practice_id`,`source`,`reff_id`,`is_active`),
 KEY `total_invoice` (`total_invoice`),
 CONSTRAINT `practice_invoice_header_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`practice_id`) REFERENCES `practice_place` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `practice_invoice_detail` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `practice_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `item_sub_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `item_type` char(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'D = DRUG; P = PROCEDURE; L = LAB',
 `item_qty` float NOT NULL,
 `item_price` float(22,2) NOT NULL,
 `discount` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `item_comission` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `item_comission_type` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '%',
 `doctor_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `item_comission_2` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `item_comission_2_type` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '%',
 `doctor_id_2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `item_base_price` float(22,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 `extra_base` float(22,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 `clinic_share` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `extra_charge` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `referred_by` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `referred_type` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `referred_comission` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `pm_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `item_type` (`item_type`),
 KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`,`practice_id`),
 KEY `practice_id` (`practice_id`),
 KEY `item_id_2` (`item_id`,`item_sub_id`,`item_type`),
 KEY `pm_id` (`pm_id`),
 KEY `timestamp_2` (`timestamp`,`practice_id`,`item_id`,`item_sub_id`,`item_type`),
 KEY `practice_id_2` (`practice_id`,`referred_by`,`referred_type`),
 KEY `practice_id_3` (`practice_id`,`item_type`),
 KEY `the_id` (`id`,`practice_id`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `item_comission_type` (`item_comission_type`),
 KEY `item_comission` (`item_comission`),
 KEY `doctor_id` (`doctor_id`),
 KEY `item_comission_2` (`item_comission_2`),
 KEY `item_comission_2_type` (`item_comission_2_type`),
 KEY `doctor_id_2` (`doctor_id_2`),
 KEY `group_id` (`id`,`timestamp`,`practice_id`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `timestamp_3` (`timestamp`,`practice_id`,`item_type`,`item_comission`,`item_comission_type`,`doctor_id`,`item_id`,`item_sub_id`,`id`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `timestamp_4` (`timestamp`,`practice_id`,`item_id`,`item_sub_id`,`item_type`,`item_comission_2`,`item_comission_2_type`,`doctor_id_2`,`id`) USING BTREE,
 CONSTRAINT `practice_invoice_detail_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`timestamp`) REFERENCES `practice_invoice_header` (`timestamp`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `practice_invoice_detail_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`practice_id`) REFERENCES `practice_place` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=968763 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `ref_practice_invoice_payment` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `practice_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `payment_method` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `pay` float NOT NULL,
 `changed` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `extra_amount` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `pay_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `pay_cal_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `user_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `refunded` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `payment_note` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 `extra` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 `other_bill` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
 KEY `practice_id` (`practice_id`),
 KEY `payment_method` (`payment_method`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 KEY `user_type` (`user_type`),
 KEY `timestamp_2` (`timestamp`,`practice_id`),
 KEY `refunded` (`refunded`),
 KEY `pay` (`pay`),
 KEY `extra_amount` (`extra_amount`),
 KEY `extra` (`extra`),
 KEY `pay_date` (`pay_date`),
 KEY `pay_cal_id` (`pay_cal_id`),
 KEY `other_bill` (`other_bill`),
 KEY `timestamp_3` (`timestamp`,`practice_id`,`refunded`,`other_bill`,`pay_cal_id`) USING BTREE,
 CONSTRAINT `ref_practice_invoice_payment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`timestamp`) REFERENCES `practice_invoice_header` (`timestamp`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `ref_practice_invoice_payment_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`practice_id`) REFERENCES `practice_place` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=255913 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And here is the EXPLAINation of the query above

```
1   SIMPLE  PIH ref PRIMARY,source,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8,total_invoice   practice_id_6   4   const   40228   Using index condition   
1   SIMPLE  PID ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,item_comission_type,timestamp_3,timestamp_4   timestamp   12  k6064619_lokadok.PIH.timestamp,const    1       
1   SIMPLE  RPIP    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded,other_bill,timestamp_3   timestamp   8   k6064619_lokadok.PIH.timestamp  1   Using where
```

The join query all is SIMPLE, yet the query took a litle bit too long. However, the data is pretty much a lot but still decent I suppose. About 200.000 rows

**FURTHER FINDINGS:**
Strange thing is if I remove this part, the query is fast (below 1 sec)

```
(RPIP.pay_cal_id >= 201805130 AND RPIP.pay_cal_id <= 201805200)
```

**@Eperbab**

Below is the explain of the suggested query:

```
1   SIMPLE  practice_invoice_header index_merge PRIMARY,source,practice_id,timestamp,is_active,practice_id_3,cal_id,practice_id_5,practice_id_6,practice_id_2,practice_id_4,practice_id_7,practice_id_8,total_invoice,practice_id_9 practice_id_9,practice_id   9,4 NULL    7422    Using intersect(practice_id_9,practice_id); Using where 
1   SIMPLE  practice_invoice_detail ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,practice_id_2,practice_id_3,item_comission_type,timestamp_3,timestamp_4   timestamp   12  k6064619_lokadok.practice_invoice_header.timestamp,const    1       
1   SIMPLE  ref_practice_invoice_payment    ref timestamp,practice_id,timestamp_2,refunded,other_bill,timestamp_3,practice_id_2 timestamp   8   k6064619_lokadok.practice_invoice_header.timestamp  1   Using where
```

Comment: Step 1: Select only the columns you actually want returned

Comment: Also, it seems immensely unlikely to me that a column called paid would have a float data type

Comment: Also, I can't find practice_id6

Comment: You can also add Indexes for the joining fields: RPIP.timestamp, PID.timestamp, PIH.timestamp

Comment: @IgrewupwithSlackware, i believe I have indexed all the timestamp on each table

Comment: When `RPIP.pay_cal_id` is removed from the query the  count of scanned rows drops from 40k to 7k, make sure you have an index on that column.

Comment: KEY `pay_cal_id` (`pay_cal_id`) <== it is indexed already

Comment: @yodann -- Do you what `(PID LEFT JOIN RPIP) JOIN PIH`?  Or `PID LEFT JOIN (RPIP JOIN PIH)`?  Please add parens to clarify.

Comment: _Note_ `LEFT JOIN..ON` should state how the tables are related, not include filtering, such as `refunded... AND other_bill...`.  The results may be different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial help:

```
PIH:  INDEX(timestamp, source, is_active, total_invoice, cal_id)
PID:  INDEX(practice_id, item commission_type)
RPIP: INDEX(practice_id, timestamp, other_bill, pay_cal_id)
```

`(RPIP.pay_cal_id >= 201805130 AND RPIP.pay_cal_id <= 201805200)` -- Sure, this may be fast.  But by itself it is using an index on `pay_cal_id`.  When put in the real query, on one side of an `OR`, the index is useless.  So, let's turn the `OR` into a `UNION`:

```
( SELECT ...
     FROM ...
     WHERE PIH.source = 'E'
      AND  PID.practice_id = 28618
      AND  RPIP.pay_cal_id >= 201805130
      AND  RPIP.pay_cal_id <  201805200
) UNION
( SELECT ...
     FROM ...
     WHERE PIH.source = 'E'
      AND  PID.practice_id = 28618
      AND  PIH.cal_id >= 201805130
      AND  PIH.cal_id <  201805200
      AND  PIH.total_invoice = 0
      AND  PID.item_comission_type <> '%'
)
```

When `EXPLAIN` says "index merge", it can almost always be improved upon by making a composite index.

Comment: finally manage to test with your suggestion, and it works. OR really does make the indexing useless. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above query could be written, as:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM practice_invoice_detail WHERE practice_id = 28618 ) as PID 

LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM ref_practice_invoice_payment WHERE practice_id = 28618 AND refunded <> 1 AND other_bill = 0 ) as RPIP 
ON RPIP.timestamp = PID.timestamp 

JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM practice_invoice_header WHERE practice_id = 28618 AND is_active = 1 AND source = 'E' ) as PIH 
ON PIH.timestamp = PID.timestamp 

WHERE 
( (RPIP.pay_cal_id >= 201805130 AND RPIP.pay_cal_id <= 201805200) 
OR (PIH.cal_id >= 201805130 AND PIH.cal_id <= 201805200 AND PIH.total_invoice = 0 AND PID.item_comission_type <> '%') ) ;
```

Please, try to add index on (practice_id, refunded, other_bill) and (practice_id, is_active, source), and post Show Explain results.

Comment: i've tried but the query still took roughly same time 6++ seconds)

Comment: According to show explain, the new indexes aren't used?

Comment: i've add the explain above, still took long seconds, but i noticed there is index_merge. i will fix the index first and see again

Comment: Multiple derived tables slows down the query significantly.  It would be better to fix the original formulation.

Comment: It depends. It may force the query optimizer to use some indexes. In this case, it didn't help.